# How to restart a countdown timer after time expired?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, countdown

**Hi folks, i would like to know how to restart a countdown timer after the time is up.
e.g. the timer should run down from 48h and restart after. Im new to android development and searched a lot through the internet but nothing really helped. thanks for ur help :)
my code in activity so far :**

```
private val handler = Handler()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.cash_riddles)

    handler.post(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            updateTime()
        }
    })

}

fun updateTime() {

    val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance()


    val eventDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    eventDate[Calendar.YEAR] = 2020
    eventDate[Calendar.MONTH] = 4 // 0-11 so 1 less
    eventDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = 4
    // i want to call the method after timer expired with 
    //eventDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]+2 (48h)
    eventDate[Calendar.HOUR] = 2
    eventDate[Calendar.MINUTE] = 5
    eventDate[Calendar.SECOND] = 20
    eventDate.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")

    val diff = eventDate.timeInMillis - currentDate.timeInMillis

    val days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    val hours = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24
    val minutes = diff / (1000 * 60) % 60
    val seconds = (diff / 1000) % 60


    verbleibende_zeit.text = "Restliche Zeit:   ${days}d ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s"
}

private fun endEvent(currentdate: Calendar, eventdate: Calendar) {
    if (currentdate.time >= eventdate.time) {

      // maybe somebody know what to type here to solve my problem
    }
}
```

Comment: im looking for a kotlin solution and i cant just call the method again cuz it´s binded to calender with fix variables. I need something like when countdown goes to zero it should restart but add 2 (48h) at eventDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

Answer (score 0):

ok I don't know which language is this but I'm guessing its kotlin when I was learning android there was a simple method to run countdown timer and I don't think is it recommended to use thread delay for countdowns.
found the link for the simpler countdown in android.https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/CountDownTimer

Answer (score 0):

firstly, i can't know where is countdown timer in your code?? You should post code where you added Countdown timer if you tried to add, because your question is about Countdown timer.
Assuming you have successfully added Countdown Timer, and if you want it to just restart when time is over you can call it again from it's onFinish() method.

if you want it to start after a delay you can add a Handler in onFinish() method like this :

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                   // call your timer again here to restart it
                     }
                }, 1000);
```

For more information about HAndler or CountdownTimer you can go and check official documentation it will definitely help you

Comment: thanks for ur help. There is nothing else in the activity but the code for countdown..

Comment: im looking for a kotlin solution and i cant just call the method again cuz it´s binded to calender with fix variables. I need something like when countdown goes to zero it should restart but add 2 (48h) at eventDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH].

Comment: the reason why i go for this complicated solution is that i want the countdown to run even when app is closed